# rhodes without rhosync

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rhodes, rhomobile

I am new in rhodes world.

I want my rhodes app to talk directly with web server

i.e I dont want to use Rhosync.

How can I achieve this?

Also I have seen about Rho AsyncHttp, is it the same I do need to do?

Comment: "I am new in rhodes world." - welcome to Earth! ;) Was there a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer following link to know more about AsyncHttp and how to use it.

[How to use Rhodes without Rhosync or RhoConnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095213/how-to-use-rhodes-without-rhosync-or-rhoconnect)

Answer (score 2):

You may use Rhodes without Rhosync.  They provide the [AsyncHttp](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services) classes and methods to enable pulling data and images from other web servers.

You may also utilize the Rhodes ORM ([Rhom](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom)) even if you are not using RhoSync.  This can greatly increase your efficiency when dealing with data objects from your backend systems, using RhoSync or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find how to start work on it and where to call those call.

[How to use Rhodes without Rhosync or RhoConnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095213/how-to-use-rhodes-without-rhosync-or-rhoconnect)

Let me know if you need further any help on this. Here I'm using this in my project.